# Enable Pointer Shadow

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, thin-client, mouse

I work for a school district and we recently began upgrading our terminal server to windows 2012 R2. Now when students log in via RDP from HP thin connect the cursor disappears, I solved the problem by unchecking "Enable pointer shadow" The problem is I need to do this for every user, I have tried looking for the setting in the registry to write a script but can't find it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an user-based GPO to deploy this registry key:

```
Key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects
Value Name: VisualFXSetting
Value Type: dword
Value data: 3
```